# Animated Gif/Image on Apple TVOS using TVML

Tags: javascript, tvos, tvml

Is there a way to display animated .gif or video using TVML?

I tried using img tag but the image doesn't animate.

Comment: I'm guessing this not supported yet...as many other things :(

Comment: We have to wait for Netscape Navigator 2.0

Answer (score 3):

Apple does not provide a way to display it by default, but actually it is possible to creating a custom TVML element.

Because TVML is "transformed" to native Views, it is possible to create any kind of View you could also create in a "native" tvOS app.

I built a sample app to show how it works here:
https://github.com/goergisn/custom-tvml-elements